# Comparison of shells?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh

Do shells have any actual advantages or disadvantages? They can all run any binary, they all support pipes and `>` (output to file). Why would one choose `bash` over `sh`, or `sh` over `ksh`, etc? Why does any shell other than `sh` exist in the first place?

Comment: Have you ever tried to use something like `dash` as your interactive shell?

Comment: @jordanm no, because I've never had any reason to use anything but `bash` other than using up two characters fewer on each line.

Comment: Technically they don't run any binaries, they run a system command that asks the kernel to do so, since only the kernel can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An executable `sh` is requisite for contemporary Unix-like operating systems.  There are various standards (e.g. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)) dictating what that means, although since "unix-like" doesn't necessarily mean "certified compliant" with anything, the reality varies somewhat.  In general, they at least implement something compatible with `sh`, the original [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).  This is why `sh` is usually a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), and "sh" is best understood today as a standard for the behaviour of whatever it links to.

`bash` is the [Bourne Again Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), which is what `sh` often links to on GNU/Linux systems (but there are other possibilities, such as `dash` and `ash`).
Bash includes all the features of sh and is intended to provide backward compatibility for sh scripts.  There are apparently some potential obscure glitches in this compatibility, but they are probably not too significant.

So in terms of functionality, bash extends sh; it does everything a `sh` should and a whole lot more.  Another popular extended sh implementation which also satisfies POSIX is the [KornShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell), `ksh`.

The other general purpose command shell lineage still used in the *nix world is [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), `csh`.  C shell, however, is not compatible with sh code, and an implementation would never be linked to `sh`.

Comment: No `sh` is no longer the Bourne shell. Just like it was no longer the Thomson shell when the Bourne shell came out and became the new de-facto standard. Now `sh` is a standard specification of a language based on a subset of ksh88, no longer an implementation. Or said otherwise, `sh` are a lot of different implementations of an interpreter for that `sh` specification. `bash` is the `sh` of the GNU project, the main reason why it's so widely used despite not being the best of shells.

Comment: Fair enough.  Well, there is the history anyway.  Somebody should write a wikipedia entry for `sh` then, since it redirects to "bourne shell".  I'll add a bit about the POSIX spec for sh... To be fair, `sh` in the context of "a shell" would refer to the bourne shell, and not a specification.

Comment: The "and a whole lot more" is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @tkbx : there's a few things mentioned in the wikipedia page -- regular expressions, associative arrays.  You'll *probably* find a ton of stuff in the NEWS or CHANGELOG file of the source.  "Differences between shells" in a pragmatic here and now sense is not really about sh and bash, since in colloquial and practical terms on a POSIX system, sh == bash.  I wrote this post to clear that up.  The Korn shell and C shell are their own story and would make for a more interesting contrast.

Comment: @goldilocks, POSIX absolutely does not imply sh == bash.  On recent Debian versions, /bin/sh is dash, not bash.  On recent Solaris versions, /bin/sh is a ksh derivative, not bash.  And on many embedded systems that can claim POSIX compliance, /bin/sh is Busybox's sh, which is ash, not bash.

Comment: @godlygeek Okay -- but I haven't said that POSIX stipulates sh == bash, or that POSIX dicates what sh means. I did write "sh is a symlink to bash on GNU (linux) systems" (which I'll add an "often" qualificater to).  The POSIX reference is an example of a  standard governing "Shell Command Language", *"the syntax of that command language as it is used by the sh utility"*.  I.e., the point is that **sh** may refer to both/either an **implementation** and/or a **standard**.

Comment: @goldilocks, I definitely agree to your point that **sh** can be used to refer to an implementation or to a standard.  I just wanted to clarify that there are lots of modern, POSIX compliant systems where bash may not even be installed by default, let alone used as /bin/sh

Comment: @godlygeek I think what I'll do is say that *nix systems require a `sh`, and that it's usually a link to something derived from the original Bourne, and then mention POSIX and the standard from S.C.'s comment.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly common differences you may find in [Difference between ksh,bash and different shells](http://www.unix.com/answers-frequently-asked-questions/12274-difference-between-ksh-bash-different-shells.html) post on unix.com
My opinion that it is like a choice different distros. Everyone chooses what he likes.